# Turn two columns into a row and a column

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like this:
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3 
A    X    87
A    Y    523
A    Z    234
B    X    33
B    Y    104
C    X    93
C    Z    24

Is it possible to turn this in to a table where ABC are the column names and XYZ are the row names? The numbers would be contained in the table.

Answer (score 0):

using the following example dataset (and the reshape2 package)

```
library(reshape2)
datas = expand.grid(Col1 = c('A','B','C'), Col2 = c('X','Y','Z'),Col3 = 1)
casteddata = acast(datas, Col1 ~ Col2, value.var = 'Col3')
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use The tidyr package

```
install.packages("tidyr")
library(tidyr)
```

I assume you have this set up in a data frame

```
#Set up data
a<-c('A',
'A',
'A',
'B',
'B',
'C',
'C')

b<-c(
'X',
'Y',
'Z',
'X',
'Y',
'X',
'Z')

c<-c(87,
523,
234,
33,
104,
93,
24)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Use the spread function

```
df_spread <- spread(df, "a","c")

> df_spread
  b   A   B  C
1 X  87  33 93
2 Y 523 104 NA
3 Z 234  NA 24
```